# Can you declare a constant array in VBScript?

Tags: vbscript

I want to use an array that I declare once at the top of my code several times.  Ex.

Const Quarters = ["Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4"]

For each Quarter q
  q.Do some work

Etc.

Can this be done in VBScript?

Comment: You might want to wait a little ( > 5 minutes) time before marking a question as answered to let more people make suggestions... ;-)

Comment: Why?  The question was answered (I can always un-mark it as such).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

An array is the result of a function call (`Array()`) in VBScript. Only literal values can be made `Const`. So: No, you can't.

Answer (score 7):

Why not just declare the array as public and then assign the array during the start of the script?

```
Public arrQuarters
arrQuarters = Array("Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4")

For Each Quarter in arrQuarters
    wscript.echo Quarter
Next
```

Answer (score 6):

You could define a function to return the array you want to use as a constant.  For example:

```
For Each q in AllQuarters
    wscript.echo q
Next

wscript.echo "element 0 = " & AllQuarters()(0)

AllQuarters()(0) = "X1"

wscript.echo "element 0 still = " & AllQuarters()(0)


Function AllQuarters()
    AllQuarters = Array("Q1","Q2","Q3","Q4")
End Function
```

Comment: Here is the GOOD answer. Although you can't declare a constant array, there is a workaround: define it as a function.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer: no. The array cannot be made `const`.

Answer (score 1):

A shorter and less error-prone solution would be:

```
Dim arr
arr = Split("Q1 Q2 Q3 Q4") : ubd = UBound(arr)
' Implied separator is " " aka 040 octal aka 32 Dec aka 020 Hex.
```

If your data might contain spaces:

```
arr = Split("Le Sage,ne pleure,ni les vivants, ni les morts", ",")
ubd = UBound(arr)
' arr(2), for instance, now contains "ni les vivants"
```

Caution: Never choose a separator that might occur in your 'atomic' data strings, or the function will split on that separator in the middle of a single piece of data.